# Transform PCollection<KV> to custom class

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, beam

My goal is to read a file from GCS and write it to Cassandra.
New to Apache Beam/Dataflow, I could find most of the hand on build with Python. Unfortunately CassandraIO is only Java native with Beam.

I used the word count example as a template and try to get rid of the `TextIO.write()` and replace it with a `CassandraIO.<Words>write()`.

Here my java class for the Cassandra table

```
package org.apache.beam.examples;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Column;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.PartitionKey;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(keyspace = "test", name = "words", readConsistency = "ONE", writeConsistency = "QUORUM",
        caseSensitiveKeyspace = false, caseSensitiveTable = false)
public class Words implements Serializable {
//    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "word")
    public String word;

    @Column(name = "count")
    public long count;

    public Words() {
    }

    public Words(String word, int count) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Words other = (Words) obj;
        return this.word.equals(other.word) && this.count == other.count;
    }
}
```

And here the pipeline part of the main code.

```
static void runWordCount(WordCount.WordCountOptions options) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        // Concepts #2 and #3: Our pipeline applies the composite CountWords transform, and passes the
        // static FormatAsTextFn() to the ParDo transform.
        p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
                .apply(new WordCountToCassandra.CountWords())
                
// Here I'm not sure how to transform PCollection<KV> into PCollection<Words> 

.apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(Words.class)).via(PCollection<KV<String, Long>>)
                }))

                .apply(CassandraIO.<Words>write()
                        .withHosts(Collections.singletonList("my_ip"))
                        .withPort(9142)
                        .withKeyspace("test")
                        .withEntity(Words.class));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
```

My understand is to use a `PTransform` to pass from `PCollection<T1>` from `PCollection<T2>`. I don't know how to map that.

Answer (score 3):

If it's 1:1 mapping, `MapElements.into` is the right choice.

You can either specify a class that implements `SerializableFunction<FromType, ToType>`, or simply use a lambda, for example:

```
.apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(Words.class)).via(kv -> new Words(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue()));
```

Please check [MapElements](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/mapelements/) for more information.

If the transformation is not one-to-one, there are other available options such as [FlatMapElements](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/flatmapelements/) or [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/pardo/).